# Send-only Email Server

Tags: email, amazon-ec2

I have a domain registered and AWS EC2 with LAMP used as a online game server.
Now I wish to set-up a e-mail server on it. But after some research, I found it to be some kind complicated.
The e-mail server will only be used to send forgot-password emails to players. So I am seeking a simple way to set-up a send-mail server without mailbox or any other functions that will compliate the things. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: While send-only servers are a good idea, there are mail servers out there that will try to connect BACK to your server as an anti-spam check. If your server isn't allowing incoming connections, your outgoing mails will get bounced.

Comment: Also, you need bounce messages to come back to you somehow. Even if you don't listen to port 25, a remote server could give you a permanent error code when you attempt to connect, which will result in a bounce message being generated and delivered locally by your own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely advise you to use [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/). You will use Amazon's infrastructure to send emails as a service.

To me, it seems to be the best solution to your use case. You won't pay much, won't need to worry about downtime or scalability, and will simply need to use their SDK in whichever language you prefer.

Take a look at the [pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/#pricing), it is quite attractive.